# Any PHP post files data causes 500

Tags: apache-2.2, files, 500-error

I'm running WHM/cPanel width mod fcgi enabled, everything works great but posting and FILES data gives a 500 (the script being called is outside the document root).

What would cause this, file permissions? - They are currently root:nobody 644

I'm posting a file of about 180kb - so much much under the maximum post allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `MaxRequestLen` was pretty small and it was failing on this - the error was going into the apache logs not the user logs.